# How to make df.describe() to display row with number of missing values

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'object': ['a', 'b', 'c',np.nan],
                   'numeric': [1, 2, np.nan , 4],
                    'categorical': pd.Categorical(['d', np.nan,'f', 'g'])
                 })
df.describe(include="all")
```

output should look like:

```
       object   numeric categorical
count       3  3.000000           3
unique      3       NaN           3
top         a       NaN           g
freq        1       NaN           1
mean      NaN  2.333333         NaN
std       NaN  1.527525         NaN
min       NaN  1.000000         NaN
25%       NaN  1.500000         NaN
50%       NaN  2.000000         NaN
75%       NaN  3.000000         NaN
max       NaN  4.000000         NaN
NaN       1      1                    1
```

**Question:** How to make `df.describe()` to display row with number of missing values for each variable (both continues and categoricals)?

Comment: can you post the expected output too?

Comment: As far as I know, `df.describe` isn't intended to do that. So the question doesn't make much sense. It simply isn't what it was built for. However, you could append to your output: `df.isna().sum()` which does what you want.